# find tomorrow day, and the day after tomorrow in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, datetime, date-formatting

I've got this code :

```
    var currentDate=new Date();
var my_date:Date = new Date();
var month=currentDate.getMonth()+1;
var day=currentDate.getDate();
var day2=currentDate.getDate()+1;
var day3=currentDate.getDate()+2;
var day4=currentDate.getDate()+3;
var day5=currentDate.getDate()+4;
var year=currentDate.getFullYear();
var tomorrow;
var three;
var four;
var five;
var months:Array = ["janvier", "fevrier", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "decembre"];
var today =(day+" "+ months[my_date.month]);
var days:Array = ["dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi"];
```

I'd like to have the day of tomorrow (and the 5 next ones).

I've tried :

```
tomorrow =(days[my_date.day+1]+" "+day2 +" "+ months[my_date.month]+" "+ year);
    trace(tomorrow);
```

It's working. I've got "samedi 5 juillet 2015"

but then I've tried :

```
 day3 =(days[my_date.day+2]+" "+day2 +" "+ months[my_date.month]+" "+ year);
trace(day3 );
```

But it results with "undefined 6 juillet 2015".

Do you know how I could do it ?

Thank you

---

EDIT

So I've add to my code for the name days:

```
var index:int = my_date.day + 2
if(index >= days.length)
{
    index -= days.length;
}
```

So here's my code :

```
var currentDate=new Date();
var my_date:Date = new Date();
var month=currentDate.getMonth()+1;
var day=currentDate.getDate();
var day2=currentDate.getDate()+1;
var day3=currentDate.getDate()+2;
var year=currentDate.getFullYear();
var tomorrow;
var three;
var four;
var five;
var six;
var months:Array = ["janvier", "fevrier", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "decembre"];
var days:Array = ["dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi"];

var today =(days[my_date.day]+" "+day +" "+ months[my_date.month]+" "+ year);
var index:int = my_date.day + 2
if(index >= days.length)
{
    index -= days.length;
}
trace(days[index+6]);
```

I've add these lines for sunday has the were a bug (saturday was "undefined") :

```
if(days[index] == "dimanche"){
 tomorrow =(days[index+6]+" "+day2 +" "+ months[my_date.month]+" "+ year);
}else{
 tomorrow =(days[index-1]+" "+day2 +" "+ months[my_date.month]+" "+ year);
}
```

And then

```
three = (days[index] + " " + day3 + " " + months[my_date.month] + " " +  year);
    four = (days[index+1] + " " + day4 + " " + months[my_date.month] + " " +  year);
    five = (days[index+2] + " " + day3 + " " + months[my_date.month] + " " +  year);
}
```

But it seems that it doesn't work with all days.

For the "third july', it's working great :

[image]

But if I change the computer date and choose, for exemple, the 23d of July

[image]

Some days are "undefined".

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show future dates using months and days arrays, you can do like this :

```
var months:Array = ['janvier', 'fevrier', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'decembre'],
    days:Array = ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi'];

function show_7_days(date:Date): void {
    var future_date:Date = new Date(date.fullYear, date.month, date.date);
    for(var i:int = 1; i < 8; i++){
        future_date.date = date.date + i;       
        trace(
            days[future_date.getDay()] + ' ' 
            + future_date.getDate() + ' ' 
            + months[future_date.getMonth()] + ' ' 
            + future_date.getFullYear()
        );
    }
}
```

And then :

```
show_7_days(new Date());

// gives : 
//      samedi 4 juillet 2015
//      dimanche 5 juillet 2015
//      lundi 6 juillet 2015
//      mardi 7 juillet 2015
//      mercredi 8 juillet 2015
//      jeudi 9 juillet 2015
//      vendredi 10 juillet 2015
```

And for a specific date :

```
show_7_days(new Date(1900, 3, 3));

// gives : 
//      mercredi 4 avril 1900
//      jeudi 5 avril 1900
//      vendredi 6 avril 1900
//      samedi 7 avril 1900
//      dimanche 8 avril 1900
//      lundi 9 avril 1900
//      mardi 10 avril 1900
```

But you can also simplify things using a [`flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html) like this :

```
var date_formater:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter('fr-FR', DateTimeStyle.LONG, DateTimeStyle.NONE);

function show_7_days(date:Date): void {
    var future_date:Date = new Date(date.fullYear, date.month, date.date);
    for(var i:int = 1; i < 8; i++){
        future_date.date = date.date + i;       
        trace(date_formater.format(future_date));
    }
}
```

Which will give you the same results.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be index-related. You're trying to access `days[my_date.day+2]`, which (depending on the day) may refer to an index out of bounds. If `my_date.day + 1` or `my_date.day + 2` is ever greater than `days.length`, you'll encounter the same issue.

You can solve this with a simple condition. For example, if my_date.day + 2 is greater than or equal to days.length, access `days[my_date.day + 2 - days.length]` instead. This ensures what we're calling is within bounds.

Example:

```
var index:int = my_date.day + 2
if(index >= days.length)
{
    index %= days.length;
}
day3 = (days[index] + " " + day2 + " " + months[my_date.month] + " " +  year);
trace(day3);
```

This should fix your issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work. I've paste your code. Here's the result of `trace(day3)` : `undefined 5 juillet 2015` (The correct result should be dimanche 5 juillet 2015).

Comment: My apologies - forgot AS3 uses zero-based indexes. I've updated the code  - now it checks if `index` is greater than *or equal to* `days.length`

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't work with all the dates. I'll edit my post in order to show you

Comment: @user3094896 Use the modulus operator instead. That should fix the issue. `index = index % days.length;` I've edited the answer